# Saving writeablebitmap to a JPG in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, bitmap, jpeg

I have a writeablebitmap object that I would like to save to JPG in silverlight , how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can i convert WriteableBitmap to jpg or some other common format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683276/how-can-i-convert-writeablebitmap-to-jpg-or-some-other-common-format)

Comment: Use ImageTools for sl http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also converting writeablebitmap object into image as

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(Width,Height);
```

//Some operation of drawing on bitmap

and then

```
Image imageFHR = new Image();
 imageFHR.Source = bitmap;
 imageFHR.Height = Height;
 imageFHR.Width = Width;
 myCanvas.Children.Add(imageFHR);
```

Comment: Thanks alot :),I have also used an extension method from ImageTools library to do so